# What would happen if you send one electron at a time through a parallel circuit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electric-circuits

[image]

If the resistor in this circuit is $R$ each of them. then parallel combination gives an equivalent resistance of $R/2$. That is, if we send 10 electrons at a time we will experience a resistance of $R/2$. Because they have two paths to go hence less resistance.

Now, if we send one electron at a time it has to through one path hence experiencing only one resistance $R$. So my conclusion is if the current is reduced the equivalent resistance should be $R$. Although my quantum mechanics knowledge is saying that it should be $R/2$ even if we send one electron a time. Has any one done this experiment?

This question is inspired by the quantum version of double slit experiment.

Comment: I don't think that reducing the current necessarily reduces the number of electrons that move.  It just means they move more slowly.

Comment: You can't just send 1 electron at a time through a circuit. There are quadrillions of free electrons in every cubic cm of copper.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot just ‘send’ single electrons through a circuit.

It is the free electrons in the metal structure that move through a wire to create a current, and it is the potential difference of the source that causes a net, mass movement of electrons through the wire.

You cannot just send an electron through a wire as a wire is not like a pipe, the electrons exist at every point in the wire all the time.

Comment: It is an answer, you can’t send one electron through a wire. It answers the question in the best way that you can with the way that electricity works. What more do you want in an answer @Self-MadeMan ?